# Java EE Rest Webservice PathParam is always 0

Tags: java, rest, java-ee-8

I created a Rest Webservice. When I want to update an entity with a specific id the PathParam is always 0.

```
@PUT
@Path("account/{accountId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Account putAccount(@PathParam("1000") int accountId, Account account) {
    return accountRepository.updateAccount(accountId, account);
}
```

URL: http://localhost:8080/example.rs.jax-master/rest/accounts/account/1000

Comment: Use this: `public Account putAccount(@PathParam("accountId") int accountId, Account account) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PathParam is the name in the uri template not the value:

```
public Account putAccount(@PathParam("accountId") int accountId, Account account) {
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html